# Bitwise operations in Elasticsearch without script?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, bitwise-operators

I am using `elasticsearch 1.5.1`. I want to perform bit wise operations on my documents in elasticsearch.

Bitwise equivalent in elasticsearch as in SQL:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx

I do not want to use any `scripting languages` as it is not preferred.
can some one provide some example on performing bit wise operations?

I tried looking out for various examples in internet but could not find any sample code /query in elasticsearch.

Comment: It seems that Lucene doesn't have this implemented: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2460.

Comment: And the corresponding ES issue here: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/975. So, you are stuck with using scripts.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Thank you for your inputs. I will propose usage of scripts.